# Neo4J Calculated property when querying

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J query that returns all properties of one NODE, what I need is to append one more property before the final result is returned, the code I am using is this:

```
const getSingleProjectQuery = 'MATCH (P:Project)' +
    ' WHERE P.id = \'' + DecryptedData.ProjectID + '\'' +
    ' TEST_calculated_property: ((toFloat(P.month)*12)/(P.amount*P.percentage))*100, ' +
    ' RETURN properties(P)';
```

But I get this error:

> unexpected variable T... Expected ',', whitespace etc...

Any idea how I can run this query? I am quite now to Neo4J..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the property in the `RETURN` statement something like this...

```
const getSingleProjectQuery = 'MATCH (P:Project)' +
    ' WHERE P.id = \'' + DecryptedData.ProjectID + '\'' +
    ' RETURN properties(P{.*, TEST_calculated_property: ((toFloat(P.month)*12)/(P.amount*P.percentage))*100)';
```